# Как отследить (перехватить) вызов метода?

Tags: java, рефлексия, аннотации

Есть метод помеченный моей аннотацией @Transaction.

package com.aimprosoft.hopak.transaction.annotation;

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)

public @interface Transaction {
}
```

Нужно, что бы при его вызове. Я мог его перехватить и поместить в свой TransactionManager

```
public interface Rollback <T>{
    T execute(EntityManager em);
}

public class TransactionManager {
    
    private static final EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Hibernate");

    public static <T> T transaction(Rollback<T> rollback){

        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        T result = null;

        try {
            em.getTransaction().begin();
                           result = rollback.execute(em);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
        } finally {
            em.close();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Допустим, у меня есть метод в DAO

```
public T findById(Long id){
TransactionManager.transaction((entityManager) -> {
            T t = entityManager.find(T.class, id);
            return t;
        });
}
```

Я хочу всё это вместить в:

```
@Transaction
public T findById(Long id){
      return entityManager.find(T.class, id);
}
```

Я подозреваю, что это делается при помощи рефлексии, но как именно? Можно ссылку на какую-то информацию. Или как правильно называется то, что я хочу сделать.

Comment: Reflections в помощь: https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections

Comment: Если задача не учебная, то лучше не изобретать велосипед, а использовать готовое aspectj или spring aop. Если же нужно/хочется свое, то смотрите, как это реализовано в спринге и aspectj и, используя те же принципы, делайте также https://www.baeldung.com/spring-aop-vs-aspectj

Comment: Вот простой пример с aspectj https://github.com/medvedev1088/aspectj-load-time-weaving-example

Answer (score 0):

Для выполнение моей задачи мне помогли: @Roman Konoval. Спасибо
Также рекомендую к просмоту
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OH6-JSQv1hg&t=976s